# strategy for eliminating or minimizing conflicts when rebasing two branches that have diverged greatly?

Tags: git

I've been working on upgrading the front end framework for my rails application for many months, this has involved upgrading from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5, from AngularJS to Angular, `.js` files slowly becoming `.ts`, etc...  So on my `frontend-upgrade` branch, lots and lots of commits..  lots of commits I'd consider garbage, as they were trial/error, various approaches to get things working.

Meanwhile master has continued to have backend development, and extremely minimal front end changes (to angularJS), but the two branches have dramatically diverged and now every time I try to rebase master on the front end upgrade branch, it's an absolute nightmare of merge conflicts, so I am just wondering if there are any recommended strategies that I can adopt for something like this?

Is there a way to do a rebase but one that ignores files in the directories  `app/javascripts/**/*` and `app/javascript/**/*` so that I can just eliminate all the billions of conficts?

Comment: Please tell us how you want the final history to look like. Can it have merges? Or should it be linear? Do you want to squash your work into a single commit (gosh, NO! That's an anti-pattern that I'm not going to help)? First thing to do: clean up your history by getting rid of all the garbage commits without changing the fork point, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebase is a great tool, but it isn't the best choice for every situation. When you have many commits that you want to keep, and rebasing yields many conflicts at each commit, it's almost always better (for both sanity and minimizing errors) to just do a back-merge for this one-off. I'd recommend just merging the latest `master` into `frontend-upgrade`, resolving the conflicts just one time, and calling it a day.

That being said, you did mention that you have "lots of commits I'd consider garbage". Even if you're going to do the back-merge, you may want to consider a little cleanup first with an interactive rebase. If you keep the same merge-base, don't change the order of any commits, and all you do is squash and re-write some commit messages, you will not have any conflicts at all (yet). This would be a one-time pass where you may be able to significantly reduce the total number of garbage commits. Note you still could even drop some commits or re-order some, but realize that as soon as you do that you open up the possibility of conflicts during this pass, so you'll have to handle those decisions on a case by case basis.

When you're done cleaning up your branch, now you would do the back-merge of `master`. Note it's possible that if you end up squashing the majority of the commits, that now you may be able to stomach the conflicts in a rebase onto `master` much better than before, so it may be worth another try before resorting to the merge instead.

**Side Note:** I only recommend using a "back-merge" of `master` into `frontend-upgrade` to resolve conflicts if the merge of `frontend-upgrade` into `master` will not be a fast-forward merge. If there's even a chance that a fast-forward merge could be possible, then I would (after cleaning up your branch), create a new temporary branch equal to `master`, and then merge `frontend-upgrade` into the temp branch. Then merge that temp branch into `master`. The reason for this is to make sure the first-parent history is preserved properly.

Comment: I ended up squashing all the garbage commits, and doing what seemed terrible (the majority of the conflicts were all involving package-lock.json and package.json over and over and over and over), which always feel like the most annoying files to deal with regarding conflicts (especially the package-lock.json) -- so my strategy ended up being creating a backup of my front end upgrade branch, and then rebasing master and doing `git checkout frontend-upgrade-backup package* && git rebase --continue` over and over and over...

Comment: so I basically just made it so that every commit had the final revision of `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

- From `master`, create a new branch `frontend-upgrade-ready`.
- Then merge (with `squash`) from `frontend-upgrade` to `frontend-upgrade-ready`.

This should give you a fresh branch with the latest code from `master` and all of the changes from the last version of `frontend-upgrade`. The `squash` should help eliminate the commit-by-commit change conflicts and concentrate on the final changes.

You can then sort out any (hopefully minor) merge conflicts, then merge the `ready` branch to `master` once you've determined everything's good to go.